# How to invoke click:prepend event or click:append event in the vuetify input fields

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to trigger the input field click:prepend function by clicking other element. 
As far now I am able to access the element using refs but in order to achieve some functionality I need to trigger the click:prepend. How can I trigger

```
<v-file-input accept="image/*" ref="fileInputSelector"></v-file-input>

this.$refs.fileInputSelector.$el.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the vuetify input element programatically in jaavascript, but you need to traverse to input from refs pointer

> `this.$refs.fileInputSelector.$el`

just points to the div wrapper of vuetify component , you have to traverse to the input by

```
var id = this.$refs.fileInput.$el.lastChild.firstChild.firstChild.lastChild.id;
document.querySelector(`input#${id}`).click();
```

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/PoozMYY?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse to the input by refs [vue] without use DOM directly

```
this.$refs.fileInput.$refs.input.click();
```